# How do I connect service to a Cloud Foundry app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm new to IBM cloud and I'm trying to build an application where I can write a text, press a button and that text is analysed by the service tone analyser returning a JSON so I can show it.

I have created an instance of said service and I have connected it to my application (a toolchain) using the 'connections' tab on the service.
[image]

I also have this code on the app.js file on my app:

```
const ToneAnalyzerV3 = require('ibm-watson/tone-analyzer/v3');
const { IamAuthenticator } = require('ibm-watson/auth');

const toneAnalyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3({
  version: '2019-10-10',
  authenticator: new IamAuthenticator({
    apikey: [API key found in service credentials],
  }),
  url: [API url found in service credentials],
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

app.post('/api/tone', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const { result } = await toneAnalyzer.tone(req.body);
    res.json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

The problem is that when I make the following call on my javascript:

```
$.post( "/api/tone", {text: textInput}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

I get the error: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sample app: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/tone-analyzer-nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are sending `req.body` to be analysed for tone. If you take a look at the API Docs - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/tone-analyzer?code=node#tone - you will see that you only need to send

```js
const toneParams = {
  toneInput: { 'text': text },
  contentType: 'application/json',
};
```

I doubt very much that `req.body` has a `toneInput` field, and if it does have `contentType` it may not be set to one of the allowable values.